# to get the current location (latitude and longitude ) by gps

Tags: android, gps, location

i am new to android.i run the application by the emulator.but always error .logcat shows:Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

> WhereAmIActivity.Java

```
package com.paad.whereami;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WhereAmIActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);//bulid locationmanager

    String provider = LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED;
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);//get lastlocation

    updateWithNewLocation(location);//pass to updatewithnewlocation
}

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location){//show Location in TextView
    String latLongString;
    TextView myLocationText;
    myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);//
    if(location!=null){//
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        latLongString = "Lat:"+lat+"\nLong:"+lng;
    }else{//
        latLongString = "No location found";
    }
    myLocationText.setText("Your Current POsition is:\n"+latLongString);//
}
```

}

> uses-permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Write this permission : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: also try with <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission
>   denied

I dont know where you are trying to access traces.txt file.But if its showing permission error 
so to solve it give it full access :)

Execute following commands in terminal

```
$adb shell
#cd \data
#chmod 777 anr
```

Keep in mind the above commands may not work if you try on actual device.You need root.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the way you get the current location . it's only the last known location . in order to get the current location , you need to request the OS to tell you when it got a new location (since it takes unknown time, based on many things ) and you might be in, and then use it.